# Table of probability

Tags: probability

A six-sided, fair die is rolled twice. Let $X$ be the sum of both throws, $Y_1$ be the result of the first throw and $Y_2$ be the result of the second. How to create the table of probability?

Comment: You should write all possible outcomes and for each  outcome count the probability of it, it will be your table of the probability function, I reckon

Comment: Having problem with writing that I don't know how to begin @DF

Comment: for example $X$ can be equal to $2$ when there are 1 on each die, so $P(X = 2) = \frac{1}{36}, P(X = 3) = \frac{1}{36} + \frac{1}{36} = \frac{1}{18}$ and etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a lot of possible "tables of probability", I'm unsure what you want to find. But these should be the probabilities you're insterested in. Have in mind that $P(X) = \sum_YP(X,Y)$

Here's $P(Y1,Y2)$

\begin{array}{c|c|c|c|c|c|c}
&1& 2 & 3 & 4&5&6 \\ \hline
1 &\frac{1}{36}&\frac{1}{36}&\frac{1}{36}&\frac{1}{36}&\frac{1}{36}&\frac{1}{36}\\ \hline
2 &\frac{1}{36}&\frac{1}{36}&\frac{1}{36}&\frac{1}{36}&\frac{1}{36}&\frac{1}{36}\\ \hline
3 &\frac{1}{36}&\frac{1}{36}&\frac{1}{36}&\frac{1}{36}&\frac{1}{36}&\frac{1}{36}\\ \hline
4&\frac{1}{36}&\frac{1}{36}&\frac{1}{36}&\frac{1}{36}&\frac{1}{36}&\frac{1}{36}\\ \hline
5&\frac{1}{36}&\frac{1}{36}&\frac{1}{36}&\frac{1}{36}&\frac{1}{36}&\frac{1}{36}\\ \hline
6&\frac{1}{36}&\frac{1}{36}&\frac{1}{36}&\frac{1}{36}&\frac{1}{36}&\frac{1}{36}\\ \hline
\end{array}

Here's $P(X,Y1)$ (or $P(X,Y2)$)
\begin{array}{c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c}
& 2 & 3 & 4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12 \\ \hline
1 &\frac{1}{36}&\frac{1}{36}&\frac{1}{36}&\frac{1}{36}&\frac{1}{36}&\frac{1}{36}&0&0&0&0&0\\ \hline
2 &0&\frac{1}{36}&\frac{1}{36}&\frac{1}{36}&\frac{1}{36}&\frac{1}{36}&\frac{1}{36}&0&0&0&0\\ \hline
3 &0&0&\frac{1}{36}&\frac{1}{36}&\frac{1}{36}&\frac{1}{36}&\frac{1}{36}&\frac{1}{36}&0&0&0\\ \hline
4&0&0&0&\frac{1}{36}&\frac{1}{36}&\frac{1}{36}&\frac{1}{36}&\frac{1}{36}&\frac{1}{36}&0&0\\ \hline
5&0&0&0&0&\frac{1}{36}&\frac{1}{36}&\frac{1}{36}&\frac{1}{36}&\frac{1}{36}&\frac{1}{36}&0\\ \hline
6&0&0&0&0&0&\frac{1}{36}&\frac{1}{36}&\frac{1}{36}&\frac{1}{36}&\frac{1}{36}&\frac{1}{36}\\ \hline
\end{array}

P(X)

\begin{array}{c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c}
& 2 & 3 & 4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12 \\ \hline
1 &\frac{1}{36}&\frac{2}{36}&\frac{3}{36}&\frac{4}{36}&\frac{5}{36}&\frac{6}{36}&\frac{5}{36}&\frac{4}{36}&\frac{3}{36}&\frac{2}{36}&\frac{1}{36}\\ \hline
\end{array}